# how to use composer.phar

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7

there is a problem in the Symfony project file , missing file compose.phar
What is the solution ?

[image]

Comment: ... install `composer` https://getcomposer.org/

Comment: I install composer But the file does not appear
!!

Comment: you need to read the documentation

Comment: What is the solution

Answer (score 2):

As like you can read in the website of composer find by a simple 'composer install' in engine web search :

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" > composer-setup.php
php -r "if (hash('SHA384', file_get_contents('composer-setup.php')) === 'fd26ce67e3b237fffd5e5544b45b0d92c41a4afe3e3f778e942e43ce6be197b9cdc7c251dcde6e2a52297ea269370680') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); }"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Make sure you have already a php installed in your system and in your path.

Other way you can also direct download the binary file which can copy as you want in your system OR on the root of your symfony2 project

**click on the "Latest Snapshot" in this page for do that** : [Composer download](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

Last other way you can read this : [Search on internet](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000082.htm)
Is not a joke ! Isn't a problem to don't understand but is a problem if you don't want search, work and read...